# How to add 2 different onclick functions to the same DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just started designing a website and I added a feature where you click a tab and it slides up to open the menu with a javascript function. But i don't know how to get the div to come back down when you click it a second time, Here's the code

```js
function myFunction() { 
  document.getElementById("toppart1").style.top="-15%";
  document.getElementById("centerbox").style.top="30%";
 }
function backUp() { 
  document.getElementById("toppart2").style.top="0px";
  document.getElementById("centerbox").style.top="23%";
 }
```

```css
body{
 font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
#frontpage{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:25%;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}
#toppart1{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:25%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
 font-size:small;
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:1;
}
#toppart1:hover{
 top:-5px;
}

#centerbox{
 background-color:white;
 border:thick black solid;
 opacity: .6;
 width:70%;
 left:15%;
 height:40%;
 top:23%;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
}
#menubuttons{
 background-color:white;
 width:auto;
 height:15%;
 top:15%;
 float:left;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 z-index:-1;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 transition:background-color 1s;
}
#menubuttons:hover{
 background-color:transparent;
 color:navy;
}
#img-arrow{
 background-color:transparent;
 transition:opacity .5s
}
#img-arrow:hover{
  opacity: .5;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="DBWEBSjAVA.js"></script>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <link href="Website.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
 <div id="menubuttons">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:15%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:29%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:43%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>

  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:57%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
 
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:71%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:84%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>



 <div id="frontpage">
  <div id="centerbox" style="left: 15%; top: 14%; height: 64%" onclick="prettyColors()">
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="toppart1" onclick="myFunction()" onrelease="backUp()" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <h1 align="center">DB WEBS</h1>
  &nbsp;<img id="img-arrow" src="Untitled.png" style="left:47%; top:67%; position:absolute;" draggable="false" height="36" width="38"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

See how it goes up? I don't know how to make it go back down when you click it a second time. Please help.

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: I don't see a toppart2 in your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function showOrHide() {
    if (document.getElementById("centerbox").style.top == "30%") {
        backUp();
    } else {
        myFunction();
    }
}

function myFunction() { 
  document.getElementById("toppart1").style.top="-15%";
  document.getElementById("centerbox").style.top="30%";
        document.getElementById("toppart1").style.transform="rotate(180deg)";
 }
function backUp() { 
  document.getElementById("toppart1").style.top="0px";
  document.getElementById("centerbox").style.top="23%";
        document.getElementById("toppart1").style.transform="rotate(0deg)";
 }
```

```css
body{
 font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
#frontpage{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:25%;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}
#toppart1{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:25%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
 font-size:small;
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:1;
}
#toppart1:hover{
 top:-5px;
}

#centerbox{
 background-color:white;
 border:thick black solid;
 opacity: .6;
 width:70%;
 left:15%;
 height:40%;
 top:23%;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
}
#menubuttons{
 background-color:white;
 width:auto;
 height:15%;
 top:15%;
 float:left;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 z-index:-1;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 transition:background-color 1s;
}
#menubuttons:hover{
 background-color:transparent;
 color:navy;
}
#img-arrow{
 background-color:transparent;
 transition:opacity .5s
}
#img-arrow:hover{
  opacity: .5;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="DBWEBSjAVA.js"></script>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <link href="Website.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
 <div id="menubuttons">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:15%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:29%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:43%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>

  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:57%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
 
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:71%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:84%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>



 <div id="frontpage">
  <div id="centerbox" style="left: 15%; top: 14%; height: 64%" onclick="prettyColors()">
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="toppart1" onclick="showOrHide()" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <h1 align="center">DB WEBS</h1>
  &nbsp;<img id="img-arrow" src="Untitled.png" style="left:47%; top:67%; position:absolute;" draggable="false" height="36" width="38"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks dude! this worked great! now my only problem is i want to get the arrow image to flip when its clicked.

Comment: Updated my answer. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to use two classes. Then you'll need only one function to toggle between two:

```js
function toggle() {
  var topPart = document.getElementById("toppart1");
  var centerbox = document.getElementById("centerbox"); 
  if (!topPart.classList.contains("open")) {
      topPart.classList.add("open");
      centerbox.classList.add("open");
  }
  else {
      topPart.classList.remove("open");
      centerbox.classList.remove("open");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
 font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
#frontpage{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:25%;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}
#toppart1{
 background-color:navy;
 width:100%;
 height:25%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
 font-size:small;
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:1;
}
#toppart1:hover{
 top:-5px;
}

#centerbox.open {
   top:30%;
}

  #toppart1.open {
    top:-15%;
  }
   

#centerbox{
 background-color:white;
 border:thick black solid;
 opacity: .6;
 width:70%;
 left:15%;
 height:40%;
 top:23%;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 position:absolute;
 transition:top .5s;
}
#menubuttons{
 background-color:white;
 width:auto;
 height:15%;
 top:15%;
 float:left;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-family:"Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
 z-index:-1;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 transition:background-color 1s;
}
#menubuttons:hover{
 background-color:transparent;
 color:navy;
}
#img-arrow{
 background-color:transparent;
 transition:opacity .5s
}
#img-arrow:hover{
  opacity: .5;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <script src="DBWEBSjAVA.js"></script>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <link href="Website.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
 <div id="menubuttons">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:15%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:29%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:43%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>

  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:57%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
 
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:71%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>
  <div id="menubuttons" style="left:84%;">
  <h1 align="center">HOME</h1>
 </div>



 <div id="frontpage">
  <div id="centerbox" style="left: 15%; top: 14%; height: 64%" onclick="prettyColors()">
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="toppart1" onclick="toggle()" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <h1 align="center">DB WEBS</h1>
  &nbsp;<img id="img-arrow" src="Untitled.png" style="left:47%; top:67%; position:absolute;" draggable="false" height="36" width="38"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give the element a class to specify whether it has been slid down or not and then toggle that class on click.

```
var el = document.getElementById('toppart1');

if(el.classList.contains("down")){
    el.classList.remove("down");
    document.getElementById('centerbox').classList.remove("down");
}
else {
    el.classList.add("down");
    document.getElementById('centerbox').classList.add("down");
}
```

then in your css add:

```
#toppart1.down {
    top: -15%;
}
#centerbox.down {
    top: 30%;
}
```